# JSON Missing ‘}’ or object member name

Tags: json

I was trying to help a friend use JSON commands in Windows 10 Minecraft which uses the JSON format. Well I entered this code below and I got the message 
“ * Line 1, Column 2 Missing ‘}’ or object member name “

```
/give @p stick 1 0 {ench:[{"id":3,"lvl":3}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to be valid JSON, that object would need double-quotes around the `ench` key:

`{"ench":[{"id":3,"lvl":3}]}`

In the future, you can use a tool like [jslint](http://jslint.com/) to validate JSON.